# How to convert a non environment texture into an environment texture to use in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv

I took a screenshot of the restaurant and I tried to use it as environment texture in cycles but it didn't work. On the attached image you can see what happened.

[image: texture]

I know that I can find a lot of environment texture on internet,but I would like to use a 3D model as base,for many reasons :

1) a lot of environment textures cannot be used because they are copyrighted

2) a lot of environment textures found on the net are not suitable for the needs

3) the environment textures found on the net are harder to modify than a 3D model

4) I haven't a camera and I'm not a photographer

5) on internet there are a lot of 3d model scenes to use

6) to render a full 3d model scenes takes time and it needs powerful computers

For example,now I used this 3D restaurant scene :

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73530

I would like to understand how to convert a non environment texture into an environment texture.

[image]

Comment: Anyway,I placed the camera on the middle of the room with coords X= 90 ; Y=0 ; Z=90 and I rotate it on the Z axis until these coords : X= 90 ; Y = 0 ; Z = -270 and everytime that I rotated the camera of 10 degree I took a screenshot. At the end I stitched all the screenshots and I created this picture : https://postimg.org/image/bd5mdrp8h/ ; it seems good,but when I use it as environmental texture,it is not nice.

Comment: I added a blender file to show you how the panorama file looks like when configured as environmental texture.

Comment: What is "the restaurant"?

Comment: yes. the goal is to create an environmental texture starting from the 3d model of the restaurant. I used autostitch to stitch all the screenshots taken by rotating the camera,but as you can see,it looks bad.

Comment: Then follow my instructions in my answer, and hit render. Don't do anything with what you've done rotating the camera around: just do it correctly with an equirectangular camera.

Comment: Maybe I'm not able to explain very well what I want to do. I need to rotate the camera and take a series of screenshots because I want to create an environmental texture from scratch !

Comment: You don't need to rotate your camera if you use my technique. Just one shot = finished.

Answer (score 2):

Add a panoramic, equirectangular camera. Done.

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it didn't work. check here : https://postimg.org/image/7aii5b1xn/81ec2b8f/

Comment: I'm using a non equirectangular texture,but I want to convert it into an equirectangular texture.

Comment: If it isn't a 360 environment texture, it never will be. I am answering your question about how to render out a 3D scene as an equirectangular environment texture.

Comment: In the screenshot of where you say it "didn't work," you simply added the *bad* texture as the background for the environment. That isn't what I was intending in my answer: you should add an equirectangular camera to the scene that you want to make an environment map from (in this case the "restaurant."

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help you the answer yourself if you want to use the image you have taken as an environment texture for LIGHTING, or if you want to use it as a BACKPLATE for visualisation purposes. If you want to use it for lighting, a simple photo will not work as it is not a spherical image. Imagine you would take a big highly polished into the restaurant, and then you take a photo of what you see in the mirrored ball you have put on the table. Thats what an environment texture needs to look like.

If you want to use the image as backplate, so that it looks like the restaurant is in the background, you need a plane uv unrwapped to the image, and then use the emission shader as output. This lead to the task of camera mapping:[image: Image as plane, Backplate]

What i'm trying to explain is that you divide environment lighting from background appearance.

Do you need more information? I hope thi will help you out.

Regards,
Karl Andreas Groß

Comment: thanks man,I sent you an email here : http://www.pixelpoems.de/home/english/contact/

Comment: thank you for your message. Please be so kind to use this forum instead of private messaging; others may benefit from reading here. you asked the following: "it seems good,but when used as environment texture,it is not :( ...but why ?" Unfortunately, your question is not clear to me. Please clarify the following: 1) is this image https://postimg.org/image/6huuvrwun/ a viewport render or the stiched panorama image? it looks rendered. 2) if 1) is a viewport render, please post the environment texture, opened in the image editor 3) Provide a screenshot of the environment world node setup

Comment: 1) is this image https://postimg.org/image/6huuvrwun/ a viewport render or the stiched panorama image? it looks rendered.

yes,it is,because I took the screenshots by rotating the camera clockwise and then I stitched using a tool

2) if 1) is a viewport render, please post the environment texture, opened in the image editor

https://postimg.org/image/6huuvrwun/

3) Provide a screenshot of the environment world node setup

https://postimg.org/image/fcx1y79lt/